How to handle duplicate elements in a custom HashMap implementation?
I'm trying to implement a simple HashMap in Java for educational purposes. I'm facing an issue where I need to handle duplicate keys. My current implementation doesn't update the value when a duplicate key is inserted; instead, it creates a new entry.
Here’s the part of my code where I handle insertion:
class HashMapCustom<K, V> {
    private Entry<K, V>[] table; //Array of Entry
    private int capacity = 4; //Initial capacity of HashMap

    static class Entry<K, V> {
        K key;
        V value;
        Entry<K, V> next;

        public Entry(K key, V value, Entry<K, V> next) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    public void put(K newKey, V data) {
        if (newKey == null) {
            return; //does not allow to store null
        }

        int hash = hash(newKey);
        Entry<K, V> newEntry = new Entry<K, V>(newKey, data, null);

        if (table[hash] == null) {
            table[hash] = newEntry;
        } else {
            Entry<K, V> previous = null;
            Entry<K, V> current = table[hash];

            while (current != null) { //we have reached last entry of bucket.
                if (current.key.equals(newKey)) {
                    if (previous == null) { //node has to be insert on first of bucket.
                        newEntry.next = current.next;
                        table[hash] = newEntry;
                        return;
                    } else {
                        newEntry.next = current.next;
                        previous.next = newEntry;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            previous.next = newEntry;
        }
    }

    private int hash(K key) {
        return Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % capacity;
    }
}


well if you look at the actual implementation of HashMap's put(), they dont create a new node unless needed. So instead of creating a new node asap, you can check if any existing entries share same key, then update its values if it does. If no entries share the same key, then you can create a new node to put into the table

If I understand your question correctly, you just have to update the value if you detect a key already exists:
public void put(K newKey, V data) {
    if (newKey == null) {
        return; //does not allow to store null
    }

    int hash = hash(newKey);
    Entry<K, V> newEntry = new Entry<K, V>(newKey, data, null);

    if (table[hash] == null) {
        table[hash] = newEntry;
    } else {
        Entry<K, V> previous = null;
        Entry<K, V> current = table[hash];

        while (current != null) { //we have reached last entry of bucket.
            if (current.key.equals(newKey)) {
                current.value = data; // Replace old value with new one.
                return;
            }
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        previous.next = newEntry;
    }
}


tl;dr
Change your implementation to nest a collection. Thus a multimap rather than simple map.
Map< Employee , Set < DayOfWeek > >

Duplicate keys not allowed
A Map in Java by definition has no duplicate keys. So your Question does not make sense.
Read the second sentence in the Javadoc:

A map cannot contain duplicate keys;

Multimap
If you want to associate multiple values to a single key, learn about multimap.
The Java Collections Framework does not provide for multimap.
You can effectively create one. Define a Map with a collection as its value, such as Set or List. For example Map< Employee , Set < DayOfWeek > >. You’ll need to write the logic to add to the nested collection.
Look to third-party multimap. Explore Google Guava or Eclipse Collections.  For your educational experience, you might want to copy or emulate their multimap interface if not implementation.
